# Meaning of 贅沢を言う

Tags: verbs, conjugations

I know all the separate meanings/translations of the sentence but I can't think of a translation which makes sense.

> 「贅沢{ぜいたく}を言{い}わなければ。」

I thought of: 
"Must tell luxury"?

The whole sentence is:

> 「一流{いちりゅう}の売{う}れっ子作家{こさっか}には程遠{ほどとお}いけれども、贅沢を言わなければどうにか食{く}っていけるだけの仕事{しごと}はある。」

Comment: Could you please provide some more information about the context of this sentence?

Comment: 一流の売れっ子作家には程遠いけれども、贅沢を言わなければどうにか食っていけるだけの仕事はある。

Answer (score 8):

贅沢 means "extravagance".
贅沢を言う means "to ask/expect too much".

～なければ can be short for ～なければならない, "must do" "have to do", but here in your example it's used in its literal sense: "If not".

Put together:

> 贅沢を言わなければ
>   "If (I) don't ask/expect too much"